# Avoid returning null whith MAX and MIN when no records are present in a reference table

Tags: sql, db2, aggregate-functions

I'm using a temporary table (TEMP_PERIODS) on which I store periods with starting and ending intervals.

Everything works as expected when the query used to populate TEMP_PERIODS is populating the target table with values however when I don't have any data the following select is returning NULL values:

```
SELECT min(FROM), max(TILL) FROM TEMP_PERIODS WITH UR;
```

returns

```
 1    2  
---- ----    
NULL NULL
```

The select without any record returned:

```
SELECT * FROM TEMP_PERIODS WITH UR;
```

A possible solution is to avoid MIN MAX selection when a counter is 0 like that:

```
SELECT count(*) into total
FROM  TEMP_PERIODS WITH UR;
```

Are they any other possible solutions when using MIN or MAX select without any data?

Comment: What did you expect to happen when there are no rows?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just to add an obvious `HAVING` clause, if you don't want your query to return rows on empty table?

```
SELECT min(FROM), max(TILL)
FROM TEMP_PERIODS
HAVING COUNT(1)<>0
WITH UR
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want no no rows returned:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT min(FROM) as min_from, max(TILL) as max_till
      FROM TEMP_PERIODS WITH UR
     ) x
WHERE min_from IS NOT NULL;
```

You probably don't need the subquery.  However, I can't test on DB2, so I'm just being safe.